# The ring of entire functions is a flat module over the ring of polynomials?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, complex-geometry

> Let $H$ be the ring of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}[z]$ the ring of polynomial functions on $\mathbb{C}$. Then $H$ is naturally a $\mathbb{C}[z]$-module. Is $H$ flat?

I heard this result from one of my friends but I'm not sure this the real statement. In any case the real statement should be asserting the flatness of some ring of holomorphic functions, and it is proved by Serre. Also it seems like there is an analogous result where $\mathbb{C}$ is replaced by complex manifolds and $\mathbb{C}[z]$ replaced by germs of holomorphic functions.

Is there any result of this kind? Could you please provide references for its proof? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, the specific example you're asking about is trivial since $\mathbb{C}[z]$ is a PID so "flat" just means torsion-free.  The more general statement would presumably be a lot harder.

Comment: For smooth varieties over $\Bbb C$, it is true that the local ring of analytic functions at a point is flat over the local ring of algebraic functions at that point. This follows since they both have the same completion (the ring of formal power series) and the completion map is faithfully flat. You may want to look up "Serre's GAGA" for more statements like or adjacent to this.